# Images show in context menu Using converter class and WPF Style

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am using  style for  context menu in this we are setting `Property="MenuItem.Icon"` and we are using binding for its value and in binding i am using converter class for setting the image source, but I am facing this problem. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I 'm not sure what you meant by conventer, but maybe this simple example can help you:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Image x:Key="Icon" Source="Icon.ico"/>
    <Style x:Key="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.Icon" Value="{DynamicResource Icon}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```